# Double Nested For Loops in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a code that first 1.) iterates through a list and replaces values in certain cells and then 2.) copy and pastes values in a list

So a made up example:

```
 Column A     Column B
   NY          500
   CA          1000
   GA          200
```

I have a for loop to iterate through column A (to replace values in cells D4,D5,D6 with NY then CA then GA) but I need a second for loop that will copy and paste those values in column B one at a time (e.g. copy and paste value in B1 into B1 after the first replacement of NY, then B2 into B2 after the replacement of CA, then B3, etc)

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim x As Integer
    NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("A1").Select
    For x = 1 To NumRows
        Range("D4") = ActiveCell
        Range("D5") = ActiveCell
        Range("D6") = ActiveCell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If i understand this correct you want to copy the value which is in Range A1 into every Range in Column D and then in Column B?

Comment: Basically, I am iterating through column A to replace the values in D4,5,6 (e.g. all 3 cells will have NY in the first iteration, then CA in the second, etc) -- however, I want to iterate through column B values only one at a time.  So copy and paste Column B1 after the NY "replacement" happens, then B2 for the CA "replacement", etc

Comment: Yes it does. Can you maybe say where the values of Column B should be copied to?

Comment: All I need is to copy and paste the value in B1 into B1, B2 into B2, etc (updated my initial comment above as well)

Comment: if you have a formula in B1, then this will be removed after the first iteration and you won't see any changes?! you will just see the value which is located in column B after the first iteration

Comment: I apologize if I am not being clear enough -- basically all I need is to combine a second for loop with the one I currently have right now that will copy and paste the value in B1 into B1, then after that the value in B2 into B2, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're asking for... in which case it can all be done in a single loop - no need for a nested loop.

```
Sub MM()

    For i = 1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        '// Assign the value of Cells(i, 1) [1 = column number] to the range D4:D6.
        [D4:D6] = Cells(i, 1).Value
        '// This is the same as copy -> paste values. Change the "2" for different column
        Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi macro man!  Do you mind just explaining what each step of the macro does?  Also,  where are the specific columns I am iterating through called -- I only ask because in my actual example it's not column a and b but actually column ET and EU

Comment: See edit above - basically just change the second number in `Cells(r, c)` to the number of the column you wish to look at.